# when i import mupdf 'lib' project in my app that build error,the log"Failed to resolve: com.artifex.mupdf:fitz:1.13.0"

Tags: mupdf, lib

when i import mupdf 'lib' project in my app that build error,the log

> "Failed to resolve: com.artifex.mupdf:fitz:1.13.0".

But i have already add the maven url in top build.gradle.Please tell why,thanks.

Answer (score 0):

...,i tried to reboot my computer ,then,the compile is successful.It maybe the android studio's bug.I hava tried every way.But it didn't work and it cost me a half of day.